# How can I round cents to dollars properly in a cash register C-program?

Tags: c, rounding, ceil

I have the code (below) for a cash register program. **The problem is that I would like to have the 50-cent at the last row properly rounded.**

What I would like: If the rest is <25 cents, I would like to round to 0. If the rest is 25-75 cents, I would like ro round to 50 cents. If the rest is 75> cents, I would like to round up to 1 dollar.

How do I solve this in the most adequate way? Can I use the "ceil"-function for this problem? If so, how?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility.h>

// This program calculates the amount of cash to be returned after a purchase 

int number(int* value, int num_size)
{
    int num = *value / num_size;
    *value %= num_size;
    return num;
}

int main (void)
{
    printf("State the price of the good in dollars and cents:\n");
    float good_price;
    scanf("%f", &good_price); //User gives input: Price of the good
    printf("State the received amount in cash in dollars and cents:\n");
    float amount;
    scanf("%f", &amount); //User gives input: Amount handed over
    int rest = amount - good_price; // Rest = Amount - Price of the good, in dollars 
    int x = (int)(rest * 100.0 + 0.5); // x = Converts the remaining rest from dollars to cents

    printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Number of 1000-dollar bills", number(&x, 1000 * 100) ); //since 1000 dollars is 10^5 cent
    printf("Number of 500-dollar bills: %d\n", number(&x, 500 * 100) );
    printf("Number of 100-dollar bills: %d\n", number(&x, 100 * 100) );
    printf("Number of 50-dollar bills: %d\n", number(&x, 50 * 100) );
    printf("Number of 20-dollar bills: %d\n", number(&x, 20 * 100) );
    printf("Number of 10-dollar bills: %d\n", number(&x, 10 * 100) );
    printf("Number 5-dollar bills: %d\n", number(&x, 5 * 100) );
    printf("Number 1-dollar bills: %d\n", number(&x, 1 * 100) );
    printf("Number of 50-cent coins: %d\n", number(&x, 50) ); //since 50 equals to 50 cent

    while(!KeyHit());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As function `number` always rounds down, simply compensate by adding $0.25 to the amount. Though it does depend on your exact requirements. The way you described it, one cut-off (0.25) is rounded up (to 0.50), the other one (0.75) is rounded down. That is mathematically inconsistent. Would it be acceptable to round an exact $0.25 down to zero?

Comment: What stops you from writing your own `round()` function?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my earlier comment. Last sentence should read: "Would it be acceptable to round an exact 0.75 up to +1.00, instead of down to 0.50?"

Comment: Do not use floating point numbers for money, most floating point implementations suffer from unexpected binary rounding. Use an integer type and calculate everything in cents (or whatever the lowest common denominator is and is readable). Then you can also solve your problem with modulo operations.

Comment: Yes Ruud, what you described would be acceptable e.g. to round exact 0.25 to zero and exact 0.75 to 1. Do you have any suggestions of how? Would adding 0,25 cent in the last row do the trick?

Comment: As per my correction: round _both_ cut-offs up. So 0.25 up to 0.50, and 0.75 to 1.00. Is that acceptable? If it is, then just replace `int rest = amount - good_price;` with `int rest = amount - good_price + 0.25;` Please run your tests and see if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would store the values in an integer representing cents. So $1.30 would be stored as 130. Then, modulus by 100 can be used to extract the cents, and integer division by 100 to extract the dollars. For example, if x is 130, then:

```
x % 100 == 30
x / 100 == 1
```

The rounding operation can be done by checking into which case x%100 falls (I would just use an if block with each of the different cases) and then adding the desired result to the dollars value determined by x/100.

Comment: How would you code the rounding operation with the if-block? It just wont work for me (Ive tried for a while, as you probably can tell)  @resiliware

Comment: I would compute and store the cents (x%100) into a temporary variable and then check if it's less than 25, or whatever other cases you care about. Good luck.